# How to count occurrences of output values in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, list, k-means

I have data (d), a snippet looks like this:

```
[[2123, 324, 234, 324, 534, 6435], [43543, 45345, 353, 5345, 543, 5435],..., n]

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

kmean=KMeans(n_clusters=3)
kmean.fit(d)

# Returns an array of either 0, 1 or 2, where each of these values is the cluster 
# that an element has been assigned to. Example found below.
kmean.labels_
```

Out:

```
array([0, 1,..., n])
```

I.e. the first list `[2123, 324, 234, 324, 534, 6435]` corresponds to cluster 0 and the second list `[43543, 45345, 353, 5345, 543, 5435]` corresponds to cluster 1.

Question: how can I determine the number of elements (the lists) assigned to each cluster value?

I've tried `len(kmean.labels_[0])` to try and find the number of elements that are e.g. 0, but that didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: how `kmean.labels_ ` is `array([0, 1,..., n])` it should be `array([0, 1, 2])`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `np.bincount(kmean.labels_)`

Comment: OP wants the length of the list